# Avoid manually decoding many strings in code

Tags: python, string, encoding, utf-8, refactoring

I work in Python. Since I have to put `.decode('utf-8')` very often, I would like to get it decoded automatically.

- Is there a way how to make all strings decoded from utf-8 automatically?

And second question:

- Is there any disadvantage?

PS: I have to decode especially strings where diacritics appears like 'Čečensko'

Here is the example:

```
result={}
if 'Ulice: ' in spans.keys():
    result['ulica']=spans['Ulice: ']
else:
    result['ulica']=''
if 'Kontaktní osoba: '.decode('utf-8') in spans.keys():
    result['kontaktna osoba']=spans['Kontaktní osoba: '.decode('utf-8')]
else:
    result['kontaktna osoba']=''
if 'Město: '.decode('utf-8') in spans.keys():
    result['mesto']=spans['Město: '.decode('utf-8')]
else:
    result['mesto']=''
if 'PSČ: '.decode('utf-8') in spans.keys():
    result['psc']=spans['PSČ: '.decode('utf-8')]
else:
    result['psc']=''
if 'Telefon: ' in spans.keys():
    result['telefon']=spans['Telefon: ']
else:
    result['telefon']=''
```

On the top of the file I have to have `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` otherwise It raises error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm spanish programmer and we have some issues with some special characters. The most awesome thing for me in python is to use:

[Python: Unicode](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

You can try it doing:

```
myString = u'Čečensko'  # Check the u before the string
```

By using unicode you avoid encoding and decoding everytime, you just need to add an `u` before any string like the example above.

If you manage all your strings as unicode characters I ensure you will avoid a lot of headaches !

Your code could be:

```
result={}
if u'Ulice: ' in spans.keys():
    result[u'ulica']=spans[u'Ulice: ']
else:
    result[u'ulica']=''
if u'Kontaktní osoba: ' in spans.keys():
    result[u'kontaktna osoba']=spans[u'Kontaktní osoba: ']
else:
    result[u'kontaktna osoba']=''
if u'Město: ' in spans.keys():
    result[u'mesto']=spans[u'Město: ']
else:
    result[u'mesto']=''
if u'PSČ: ' in spans.keys():
    result[u'psc']=spans[u'PSČ: ']
else:
    result[u'psc']=''
if u'Telefon: ' in spans.keys():
    result[u'telefon']=spans[u'Telefon: ']
else:
    result[u'telefon']=''
```

But you need to use the unicode string everywhere, the keys of the dictionary you're using in this function should be created using also unicode characters, once you get used to use it everywhere it saves you a lot of time.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried to change ['PSČ: '.decode('utf-8')] to [u'PSČ'] and it works! It is way better than writing it explicitely.

Comment: I fought too many time with the encoding... I love my country but I hated our  'ñ'  during too many time until I began to use unicode

Comment: Yes, we, slovakian have č,š,č,ť,á,ú,í,ó etc. it's sometimes horrible.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary in python is basically a class that implements [few methods](https://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types), for you important probably:

- [`__contains__(self, key)`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)
- [`def __getitem__(self, key)`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)
- [`def __setitem__(self, key, value)`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__)
- [`def __delitem__(self, key)`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__)

And you basically just want them to encode every key to bytes if it isn't already, for example like this:

```
if isinstance(key, str):
    return key.encode('utf-8')
return key
```

So you can just simply wrap default dictionary to your own:

```
class SDict(dict):
    @staticmethod
    def prepare_key(key):
        if isinstance(key, str):
            return key.encode('utf-8')
        return key

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return super().__contains__(self.prepare_key(key))

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return super().__getitem__(self.prepare_key(key))

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        return super().__getitem__(self.prepare_key(key), value)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        return super().__delitem__(self.prepare_key(key))
```

You can initialize it from common `dict` object:

```
>>> d1 = {b'a': 1, b'b': 2}
>>> d2 = SDict(d1)
>>> d2
{b'a': 1, b'b': 2}
```

`in` operator works properly:

```
>>> 'a' in d1
False
>>> 'a' in d2
True
>>> 'c' in d2
False
>>> 'c' in d1
False
```

And item selection also works proplerly:

```
>>> d1['a']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'a'
>>> d1[b'a']
1
>>> d2[b'a']
1
>>> d2['a']
1
```